# Display message after form validation & before result page

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that uses the excellent jQuery validation plugin. This is a multi-stage form, one of which involves uploading files, which are scanned for viruses before being accepted.

As the upload & virus scan can take a while, I would ideally like to show the user an interim message, preferably in a modal-overlay style, which stays around until the results page.

In my head this is quite simple, but I can't get it working (I have the message code sorted). The trouble seems to be that my message overlay has to trigger after successful validation & without stopping the form from submitting.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I'm starting to think I'm too close to it and need to look for another solution. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Incidentally, this is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656583/scan-php-uploads-for-viruses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)?

Comment: Thanks, I was and am. Went back after a break & got it working. Was definitely "too close".

Answer (score 1):

I would use either the [blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) or [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) plugin for this.