# How can I display a status message while a file is uploading?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can any one give a simple method using JavaScript to display a status message while file is uploading and fade away when file is uploaded?

Comment: window.status = "Uploading...";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <style type="text/css">
     #loadingMessage {
        position: absolute;
        top: WHEREVER;
        left: WHEREEVER;
        z-Index: 100;
     }
  </style> 


   <div id="loadingMessage" style="visibility:hidden;">This page be uploading!</div>

    <form id="yourForm"> ... </form>

    <script>
       document.getElementById("yourform").onsubmit = function() {
          document.getElementById("loadingMessage").visibilty = "visible";
          return true;
       };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using Jquery plugins you can apply many
>   effects while uploading and after
>   uploaded.

Check out this demo links :
http://valums.com/wp-content/uploads/ajax-upload/demo-prototype.htm
http://www.uploadify.com/demo/

Jquery Example : 
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your server-side language. If you're using PHP, you need something like this: [Martin Jansen](https://martinjansen.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I was in a [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700347/display-message-after-form-validation-before-result-page) a while back and ended up using the excellent [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <style type="text/css">
     #loadingMessage {
        position: absolute;
        top: WHEREVER;
        left: WHEREEVER;
        z-Index: 100;
     }
  </style>

    <div id="loadingMessage" style="visibility:hidden;">This page be uploading!</div>

    <form id="yourForm"> ... </form>

    <script>
       document.getElementById("yourform").onsubmit = function() {
          document.getElementById("loadingMessage").visibilty = "visible";
          return true;
       };
    </script>
```